# Ruby Iterating Through Array for Method Names

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, methods

I have an object that I want to output a bunch of methods' results from.  I have an array of method names and want to iterate through them:

```
img = Magick::Image::read('/Users/rich/Projects/imagemagick/orig/IMG_4677.jpg')[0]
atts = "background_color base_columns base_filename base_rows bias black_point_compensation".split(' ')

atts.each do |i|
  puts img.i  # problem evaluating i
end
```

I have tried string interpolation and `eval` but I can't get it to realize it's a method call.

Is there a way I can apply an array as method names to an object?

Comment: more appropriate syntax would be `%w(background_color base_columns base_filename base_rows bias black_point_compensation)` or `%i(background_color base_columns base_filename base_rows bias black_point_compensation)`. `%w()` implies a space separated list and will convert to a `String` based `Array` (basically the same as your `split(' ')`). `%i()` is the same but will convert to a `Symbol` based `Array` given the items comply with appropriate `Symbol` naming conventions

Comment: I was having issues with that so I ran to .split(' ').  Yes you are correct.

Comment: `%i` is probably better because the strings will be converted to symbols internally for the method lookup. Might be slightly more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
atts = "upcase downcase".split

atts.each do |i|
  puts 'hEllO'.public_send(i)
end

#HELLO
#hello
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Great answer. Keep in mind that `#public_send`'s big advantage over `#send` is that you can't accidentally call a private method, so it should be your default unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.